# SetRange method returns NoneObject in pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I'm trying to make some part of text in table cell in word document bold with python. But I can't figure out how to do it.

I've already tried using range method with parameters, but it returns string, instead of range object. Now I'm trying to call SetRange method of Range object in Python, but it makes my Range object NoneObject.

```py
test = table.Cell(start_row + i, 3).Range.SetRange(1, 10).Bold = True
```

Code crashes with

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Bold'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using it properly. Check [[MS.Docs]: Range object (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range):

- *SetRange* - one of its methods, which doesn't return anything (translated to *Python* - returns *None*)
- *Bold* - one of its properties

So, you shouldn't chain the 2. Modify your code to:

```py
range_obj = table.Cell(start_row + i, 3).Range
range_obj.SetRange(1, 10)
range_obj.Bold = True
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked as I wanted. I want to add, that in the end second line should look like this `range_obj.SetRange(range_obj.Start + 1, range_obj.Start + 10)`. This way it will affect only characters inside cell.

Comment: @AlexanderZh.: That's just a detail :)